Expected type 'MyEnv', got 'Env' instead
I have created my custom environment from OpenGym, and I'm getting the previous warning on this line:
env: MyEnv= gym.make('gym_envs/MyEnv-v0')

When I remove MyEnv, I don't get the warning there but then I get a warning "Unresolved attribute reference 'action_type' for class 'MyEnv'" on the following line:
agent = QLearningAgent(env.action_space, env.observation_space.n, env.action_type.n)

Any idea how to get rid of the warnings?
I tried to write a wrapper to return ATMEnv object instead of Env but it didn't solve the problem

We need to see some more code for this problem. Could you provide the full error and maybe partial code snippetes?
